# What is the purpose of having a remote test environment?

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rspec, environment

I am currently building a Rails API application with the following environments:

- Production (remote on Heroku with it's own remote PG database)
- Staging (remote on Heroku with its own remote PG database)
- Development (local with a database that I import from time to time from Heroku production db)
- Testing (local with its own database that I import from time to time from Heroku production db)

I have just started getting into the TDD flow so am pretty new to testing and have a few questions.

Is it best practice to have a remote testing environment as well in order to better simulate the production environment?

If so, how do I constantly run tests against this as I write code (or is the point of this to just run the tests before deploying to staging and then to deployment and then just use local test environment for the continuous testing?)